# Cannot find module 'contentlayer/generated' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, next.js, md5

I'm using **NextJS 13.3** (app directory), and I'm trying to use **contentlayer** to serve my **mdx** files.

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "contentlayer/generated": ["./.contentlayer/generated"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts", ".contentlayer/generated"],
}
```

### contentlayer.config.js

```
import { defineDocumentType, makeSource } from 'contentlayer/source-files';

export const Post = defineDocumentType(() => ({
    name: 'Post',
    contentType: 'mdx',
    filePathPattern: 'posts/*.mdx',
}));

export default makeSource({
    contentDirPath: 'content',
    documentTypes: [Post],
});
```

### app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx

```
import { allPosts } from 'contentlayer/generated';
```

This import gives me the following error:

> Cannot find module 'contentlayer/generated' or its corresponding type
> declarations

Answer (score 2):

this Github issue might help:
https://github.com/contentlayerdev/contentlayer/issues/415

Also, don't forget to set `next.config.js`(or `next.config.mjs`) settings:

```js
import { withContentlayer } from 'next-contentlayer'

export default withContentlayer({ ... })
```

In my case, the problem was solved when I wrote `yarn contentlayer dev`(you can use any other package managers(`npm`, `npx`,...) other than `yarn` for sure) command after following the get started tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Following this issue (thanks to @yejinc), I'm **contentlayer** script to `dev` in **package.json** as a local workaround:

```
"dev": "contentlayer dev & next dev"
```

It seems that this issue is fixed in the latest release of **contentlayer**: https://github.com/contentlayerdev/contentlayer/releases/tag/v0.3.2