# contentlayer with Nextjs import issue

Tags: next.js, contentlayer

I've also checked this one: [Cannot find module 'contentlayer/generated' or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76070180/cannot-find-module-contentlayer-generated-or-its-corresponding-type-declaratio) but as still there is no proper solution I need to ask with better code.

Actually it's not my own code, it's this one: https://github.com/frontendweb3/minimalist

It's returning the same error code as the above ticket:
Cannot find module 'contentlayer/generated' or its corresponding type declarations

[image]

Is there any proper fix to this one? I've also created a ticket to the owner of this code.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks